# Sql query to populate 0's for missing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, highcharts

To populate a stacked and grouped highchart I need to add some 0 values into my data. I've tried with a numbers table but could not figure out how to add 0's for every empoloyee missing per date. So I have:

TABLE (Datum, Employee, Number, Stack)

```
2012-10-13 00:00:00.000 Nick    3   corporate
2012-10-14 00:00:00.000 Jack    1   private
2012-10-15 00:00:00.000 Yannick 1   corporate
2012-10-15 00:00:00.000 Jack    2   corporate
```

and I need:

```
2012-10-13 00:00:00.000 Nick    3   corporate
2012-10-14 00:00:00.000 Nick    0   corporate
2012-10-15 00:00:00.000 Nick    0   corporate
2012-10-13 00:00:00.000 Jack    0   private
2012-10-14 00:00:00.000 Jack    1   private
2012-10-15 00:00:00.000 Jack    0   private
2012-10-13 00:00:00.000 Yannick 0   corporate
2012-10-14 00:00:00.000 Yannick 0   corporate
2012-10-15 00:00:00.000 Yannick 1   corporate
2012-10-13 00:00:00.000 Jack    0   corporate
2012-10-14 00:00:00.000 Jack    0   corporate
2012-10-15 00:00:00.000 Jack    2   corporate
```

do I need to use a cursor or is there a better trick?

Comment: what rdbms are you using? sql server, mysql, oracle?

Comment: Mmmh... you should consider using CASE WHEN to decode the output, instead of "poisoning" the database with a lot of zeroresults...

Comment: @Swift not adding to database, just trying to create a SELECT which will give me the extra rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    select dates.Datum, employees.Employee, isnull(tbl.Number,0), employees.Stack
      from (select distinct Datum from tbl) dates
cross join (select distinct Employee, Stack from tbl) employees
 left join tbl on tbl.Datum=dates.Datum and tbl.Employee = employees.Employee
                  and tbl.Stack = employees.Stack
```

Comment: this is very good, but will only work when there is at least one record for a date

Comment: It does say `for every employee missing per date` which I figured to be `per date (in data)`